# Avoid parameter duplication in CQRS RESTful ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, cqrs

I'm trying to build a RESTful API using CQRS (with MediatR) in ASP.NET Core 6.

The issue I'm facing is when trying to expose child entities.

Consider a `ItemProperty` to have many `ItemPropertyOptions`.

The query I'm trying to expose is the following:

```
public record GetItemPropertyOptionsQuery(string PropertyReference, int PageNumber = 1, int PageSize= 10) : IRequest<PaginatedList<ItemPropertyOptionDto>>;
```

So in the controller my initial attempt was the following:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("ItemProperties/{propertyReference}/Options")]
public async Task<ActionResult<PaginatedList<ItemPropertyOptionDto>>> GetAsync([FromQuery]GetItemPropertyOptionsQuery query, string propertyReference)
{
    if (query.PropertyReference != propertyReference)
    {
       return BadRequest("You are querying for a different object.");
    }
    return Ok(await Mediator.Send(query));
}
```

As you can see, the main issue is that I need the property reference to process my query, but that is also part of the URL, so I have them duplicated. This means that the consumer of the API has to include them twice and I have to check for them to be equal.

[image: OpenAPI]

The resulting call is something like:

```
/ItemProperties/test/Options?PropertyReference=test
```

This is a smell to me but I'm not sure how to solve it.

A first idea was to not expose directly the query but a different object that does not include this parameter and the create the Query myself, but I would need to create an extra record and match it to the query/command fields for every endpoint I create, and that doesn't sound very clean from a maintainability PoV since every time I change the Query to include a new parameter I need to do the same in the Request.

Or do you think it would be ok this way?

```
public record GetItemPropertyOptionsRequest(int PageNumber = 1, int PageSize= 10);

[HttpGet]
[Route("ItemProperties/{propertyReference}/Options")]
public async Task<ActionResult<PaginatedList<ItemPropertyOptionDto>>> GetAsync([FromQuery]GetItemPropertyOptionsRequest request, string propertyReference)
{
    var query = new GetItemPropertyOptionsQuery(propertyReference, request.PageNumber, request.PageSize);
    return Ok(await Mediator.Send(query));
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this, return a list of `ItemPropertyOptions` for a given `ItemProperty`?

Comment: If you wanna just compare the two PropertyReference coming from the client in your RESTful API and return a bad request when they are different, why not do it on your client side (frontend)?

Comment: @Peppermintology yes

Comment: @MajidShahabfar I could check on the client if I'm the one consuming the API, but it will be public so I need to check on the server just in case

Comment: @Pinx0 so in this case just rename the propertyReference argument of GetAsync method. For example, change it to propertyRef

Answer (score 0):

> What are you trying to achieve with this, return a list of
> ItemPropertyOptions for a given ItemProperty?

@Peppermintology yes

In which case you do not require the additional (and superfluous second) `propertyReferece` parameter.

All you require is the first `propertyReference` parameter. That should operate as the lookup key for the relevant `ItemProperty` entity in your database and then all you need to do is retrieve the releated `ItemPropertyOptions` as a relationship.

So your URL would look as follows:

```
/item-properties/{propertyId}/options
```

Then you would use the `propertyId` parameter in your query handler to obtain your records and relation opptions. That might look something like:

```
var results = await _dbContext.PropertyItems
    .Where(item => item.Id == propertyId)
    .Include(item => item.Options)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: But how does this work with having also other parameters for the query such as pagination? If it's the only parameter yes it is easy I take it from the URL, but if there are more (there is a body of the request) how do those two options combine?

Comment: You would still handle that the same way. I just omitted pagination from my answer to keep things simple.